# Kant tells us that necessity is an indication of a priori concepts

Tags: kant, necessity

It is easy enough to grasp that necessity does not inhere in nature but it is more difficult to explain. Is there a clearer explanation?

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative explanation of necessity generally, or of what Kant thought about necessity?

Comment: I withdraw the question.